# Shopify Version Control

Tags: version-control, shopify

I've been researching version control for Shopify but I'm still unsure what kind of approach to take. (I've looked into Beanstalk, Slate, etc.)

We have 4-5 team members who have access to our code but usually it's only 1 person (me) who makes changes. We make a lot of small updates almost daily, and push bigger updates every couple weeks.

We would like to use version control to track changes and to keep backups.

My questions are...

- What are you using for Shopify version control?
- Do I need version control if it's usually just one person making changes?
- Are there any other recommendations for handling code updates and backups?
- Is version control a hassle when making a bunch of small changes?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Shopify development workflow is much different from WordPress or other self hosted projects. However, Shopify has developed some tools and recommendations list to ease the pain. We use [Theme Kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) and [DeployBot](https://deploybot.com/) in our workflow.

We use Theme Kit configured with Dev store to work on new features and updates.
Version control is done using Git with Bitbucket. Once the feature branches gets merged to Master, the Master branch is automatically deployed to multiple Shopify stores using DeployBot.

To integrate Shopify with DeployBot you can have a look at [Upload your themes from GitHub or Bitbucket to Shopify](https://deploybot.com/blog/upload-your-themes-from-github-or-bitbucket-to-shopify)